# Keycloak settingup with with UWP

Tags: uwp, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Is anyone has overcome setting up Keycloak with a UWP application?
Tried using nuget package Identitymodel and called the Keycloak using that. But no luck with that. Has anyone tried Keycloak with UWP or a good tutorial?

```
 var options = new OidcClientOptions
            {
                Authority = "http://localhost:8080",
                ClientId = "app",
                Scope = "openid email roles",
                RedirectUri = "io.identityserver.demo.uwp://callback",
                ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect,
                LoadProfile = true,
                
               
            };
            
            var client = new OidcClient(options);
           
            var result = await client.LoginAsync(new LoginRequest());
```